# How do I use the datatable to retrieve data in my table from SQL Server in c #

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

i want to retrieve data from my database to my window that displays all information about a student in the "Student View" where I choose a studentid and then fill all the information. Thanks in advance this is my code.

Solution 1, but not effective because i have many students and its not read from my database.

```
public override DataTable getStudentData()
    {    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("StudentID");
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Gender");
    dt.Columns.Add("Streetadress");
    dt.Columns.Add("ZipCode");
    dt.Columns.Add("Birthdate");
    dt.Columns.Add("StudentType");
    dt.Columns.Add("City");
    dt.Columns.Add("Country");
    dt.Columns.Add("program");
    dt.Columns.Add("PgmStartYear");
    dt.Columns.Add("credits");
    dt.Rows.Add("studentid", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Gender", "Adress", "Zipcode", "Birthdate", "Studenttype ", "City", "Country", "Programname", Startyear, credits);

return dt;
}
```

Solution that i want to be possible is something like this:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Rows.Add(["studentid"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["firstname"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["lastname"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["gender"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["birthdate"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["streetadress"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["zipcode"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["country"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["city"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["studenttype"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["programname"].ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(["year"].ToString());
```

Comment: Have you tried using entity framework to automatically generate classes for all of your tables?

Comment: I do not know what you mean really because I am a beginner and playing around with both C # and SQL Server. What I have done is linked me up against my database and then implemented all the code for reading and add students. Now I want to see the students I have added. Wich frameworks do you mean i need to use?

Comment: If you are looking for a coding approach that requires less manual coding, then one way is to use entity framework, which is a bunch of libraries and user interfaces that make interfacing to a database easier for coders and autogenerates a lot of code for you. I don't know if you're building a desktop or a web app but here is an example for a desktop app: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/753510/SocialClub-A-Sample-application-using-Csharp-NET-E. It would help to edit your question and clarify which. If you are just getting started, desktop is definitely easier than web.

Comment: So to "see the students I have added", do you want to see them in a webpage, a desktop application, a report, a phone? Again if you are just getting started, I suggest desktop.

Comment: If you're a beginner I suggest starting with [ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET). Yes, Entity Framework will require less “manual coding” but it just has too much magic going on for beginners to understand.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I run my code in Visual Studio and run the program there and working in a window that pops up, where I have put in comboboxes labels and text boxes, etc. It is a simple program but have only stuck, may need to rest up a little bit and look at the frameworks that exist.

Comment: To explain what it looks like to me. I'm running Visual Studio with all my code. Then comes a window where I log / disconnect myself from my database of login. Since I have options that a program to fill in a student and save. Now I try to select one student from there and get all the information available about him.

Comment: The code shown has nothing to do with retrieving data from your database. It's really not clear what your specific problem is. As already suggested, you should find a tutorial to get known to the basic concepts and different approaches mentioned in other comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of a tutorial or an article about loading from Database using C#....

The suggested answer before is one way (and will work perfectly)... 
and you can find another way on this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/669312/load-all-table-in-dataset-from-sql-database-in-Csh):

Although since your are new to C# and still learning, i highly recommend you to follow the "Solution 2" provided in page which uses stored procedures instead of direct SQL, since its the correct way to connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to retrieve data from SQL Server

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public DataTable StudentView()
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Server= localhost\SQLINSTANCENAME; Database= DBNAME; Integrated Security=True;");

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("QUERY", sqlCon);

    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);

    return dtbl;
}
```

Replace

- `SQLINSTANCENAME` with your own SQL Server instance name, e.g. `SQLEXPRESS`, `SQL2008`
- `DBNAME` with your database name
- `QUERY` with `SELECT column-list FROM your-table`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I have already connected to my database and try something like this:

```
           try
            {
            SqlCommand read = new SqlCommand();
            read.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            read.Connection = connect;
            read.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [viewstudent]";
            SqlDataReader get;
            get = read.ExecuteReader();

            while (get.Read())
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(["studentid"].ToString(); get["firstname"].ToString(); get["lastname"].ToString(); get["gender"].ToString(); get["birthdate"].ToString(); get["streetadress"].ToString(); get["zipcode"].ToString(); get["country"].ToString();
                get["city"].ToString(); get["studenttype"].ToString(); get["programname"].ToString(); get["year"].ToString(); get["credits"].ToString();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Good!");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error try again!");
        }
        connect.Close();

        return dt;
    }
```